# alinear mis datos cuando lo imprima en la consola de Eclipse (Java)

Tags: java

¿alguien podría orientarme a tratar de alinear mis datos cuando lo imprima en la consola?.

Ya tengo todo, sólo necesito que quede en orden los datos, gracias.

**Clase 1**

```
public static void imprimir() {
        System.out.println("Nombre Materia 1 Materia 2 Materia 3 Promedio Status");
        for(int i=0; i<alum.length; i++) {
            alum[i].imprimir();
```

**Clase 2**

```
public void imprimir() {
    System.out.println(nombre+" "+materia1+" "+materia2+" "+materia3+" "+promedio+" "+status);
```

Comment: ponle un `\t` entre cada valor a separar o usa printf en vez de println y mándale el formato desde allí para que te respete siempre los mismos espacios.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendí, independiente de como se seteen los valores al objecto alum, tu siempre quieres mostrar los elementos ordenados cierto?

Si este es  el caso puedes hacer lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego iterar la lista de objecto e imprimir el toString, de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Abajo en la consola se puede ver como se muestra el resultado